# ¿Cómo accedo a los métodos de una clase hijo, teniendo solo relación con la clase padre?

Tags: java-8, herencia

Tengo un digrama de clases que consta de tres clases:

1. Clase **Empresa** ( esta tiene una *relación* con la clase
   **LineasTelefonicas**)
2. Clase **LineasTelefonicas**
3. Clase **LineasCelular** ( esta *hereda* de **LineasTelefonicas**)

   - en la clase *LineasCelular* tengo el
     método:**+calcularCostoLlamadasCelular():double**
   - en la clase *LineasTelefonicas* tengo el método: **+calcularCostoLlamadasTelefonicas():double**
   - en la clase *Empresa*
     tengo el metodo: **+calcularTotalCostoLlamadas():doble**

para resolver el metodo de la clase empresa necesito sumar :
*+calcularCostoLlamadasTelefonicas():double*  **+**  *+calcularCostoLlamadasCelular():double*

pero al momento de llamar el método perteneciente a la clase hijo(+calcularCostoLlamadasCelular():double) al compilar me aparece error **"Cannot find symbol"** porque ese método no existe en *LineasTelefonicas*.

***¿Cómo puedo acceder al método desde empresa?***

Comment: Hola y bienvenida, por favor puede colocar el código fuente de las tres clases y el error. En principio una clase padre no puede acceder a los métodos de las clases hijos, pero las clases hijos si pueden acceder a los métodos de las clases padres.